# Selecting just a couple of characters in the VS code editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, select, text, windows-8, edit

I'm used to Visual Studio 2008, where you can drag text in the code editor just fine.

Now I'm on VS 2010, and when I try to select just two characters in the code the editor doesn't select anything at all, but if I drag mouse over the third character, it selects all three characters.

Maybe it's a feature I don't understand, but it starts bothering me.

Is there a way to make selecting characters with mouse work in the old way, as in VS 2008?

I have tried uninstall that plugin and reset vs settings that dont't help.

There is video of it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wNFQxpCAEQ

PS: Im running Windows 8 RP x64.

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem (VS2010 Prof)... sounds very strange

Comment: Can you try to select only one character using mouse?
I can not do this. To select one character before I mast select three than drag back to one.

Comment: Yes, I can without issue.  Sounds like either something on your computer (does it happen in any other text editor? Notepad, Word, Outlook, etc?) or you have a particular VS plugin that could be effecting it?

Comment: There is only one VS plugin installed - Qt VS Add-in. But it was installed on VS2008 too and it works there good. On notepad, word outlook and any other programs there is no issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like it's possible to temporarily disable VS plugins, but my **guess** would be that this "Qt" plugin you've mentioned would be something to do with it. You could [try removing the plugin from VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228765%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as long as you still have it to install again afterwards.  Otherwise, sorry, can't help any more than that

Comment: I have tried uninstall that plugin and reset vs settings that dont't help.
Thanks for replay. Hope I will find solution. There is video of it http://youtu.be/8wNFQxpCAEQ

Comment: In that case, I would suggest doing a reinstall of VS. (And sorry, but I'm not clicking a link to "youtu.be"... looks like a phish to me)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wNFQxpCAEQ

Comment: Yeah, that is **really** strange!! If the plugin hasn't worked, then I would recommend a complete VS uninstall / reinstall

Comment: I'm intrigued... did the reinstall work?

Comment: Reinstalled on Windows 8 RTM x64.
It works good now.